# 400 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL

Tags: java, api, http, youtrack

I am currently working on renewing youtrack api methods in the project since old youtrack api has been deprecated, and when I'm trying to send requsts such as:

```
https://youtrack.my.ru/api/admin/customFieldSettings/bundles/version/
https://youtrack.my.ru/api/issues?query=sampletext
```

and I am getting

```
400 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
```

Thr problem is not in the requsts itself, because i tryed using the same requests with the same bodies and headers via postman and it worked perfectly, so i assume it is something with my java restTemplate config, you can se samples of me sending requests below:

```
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.POST, versionsEntity, String.class);

    logger.debug("Adding new version response status is {}", response.getStatusCode());
    return response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED;
```

And this is how I add body to the requst (the body is the versionBundle object):

```
versionsEntity = new HttpEntity<>(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(versionBundle), entity.getHeaders());
```

You can also see that youtrack api itself is perfectly ok with me using POST requst to update a bundle here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/youtrack/devportal/operations-api-admin-customFieldSettings-bundles-version.html#update-VersionBundle-method

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I have also tried different restTemplate methods, such as put and postForEntity, nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Somehow problem was resolved by creating new RestTemplate with autowired templateFactory, before i was autowiring RestTemplate, if someone can explain me why is this helped it would be great